# $\widehat{A}$ is $\widehat{m}$-formally étale over $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In example 28.1 from the book Commutative ring theory of Matsumura, it is told that the completion $\widehat{A}$ of the local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is $\hat{m}$-formally smooth over $A$.

Recall of $\hat{m}$-formally-smooth: if $C$ is an $A$-algebra with a squared zero ideal $I$, given $u:\widehat{A}\to C/I$ continuous for the discret topology of $C/I$ (that is $u(\hat{m}^k)=0$ for some $k$) there exists a lifting of $u$ to $C$.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\widehat{A} @>{u}>> C/I\\
@AAA @AAA\\
A @>{\lambda}>> C
\end{CD}

There is a clue: use that $\widehat{A}/\hat{m}^k\simeq A/\mathfrak{m}^k$.

If one has a $A$-algebra $C$ and with squared zero ideal $I$, a morphisme $u:\widehat{A}\to C/I$, if $u(\hat{m}^k)=0$ then $u$ induces
$$ \widehat{A}\to \widehat{A}/\hat{m}^k=A/\mathfrak{m}^k\to C/I $$
so that it is enough to have a lifting of $A/\mathfrak{m}^k\to C/I$ to $C$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A/\mathfrak{m}^k @>{u}>> C/I\\
@A{s}AA @A{\sigma}AA\\
A @>{\lambda}>> C
\end{CD}
but is seems it should require that $\lambda(\mathfrak{m}^k)=0$ which is not in the hypothesis.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the context I assume that $\lambda$ denotes tha structure map $A \rightarrow C$ and the discussed lift should be a map $\widehat{A}\rightarrow C$ cutting the suggested square into two commutative triangles.)

The lower of the two squares that you sketched implies that $\lambda(\mathfrak{m}^k)$ lands in $I$, which is a square-zero ideal. So while we don't have $\lambda(\mathfrak{m}^k)=0$ necessarily, we do have at least $\lambda(\mathfrak{m}^{2k})=0$. So upon replacing $A/\mathfrak{m}^k$ in your diagram by $A/\mathfrak{m}^{2k},$ you get the desired lift.

Comment: That's it! Thanks